# Requesting certificate for JWKS from CA

Tags: oauth, jwt, jwk

If I want to use a non self-signed cert to use in a JWK file, what type of cert should I request from the CA? SSL or Code-signing cert?

Answer (score 0):

An SSL cert will be fine, such as a PKCS#12 file with a P12 extension, and is a mainstream option. Though you only really need the `digital signature` and `non-repudiation` characteristics from [this table](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/external-auth-server/2.4.2?topic=extensions-keyusage-extension).

It is just a keypair though, so when tokens are verified, signature checks don't chain up to a CA. So it is also valid to create the keypair using a JWT library or a tool like openssl.